# Gaussian Elimination with Partial Pivoting (what am I doing wrong?)

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

This should be  a simple question Im using gaussian elimination with pivoting to solve
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2 &  1 &  0 &  3 \\ 
1 & -1 &  4 & -4 \\ 
3 & -1 & -2 &  4
\end{array}\right]$$
**First I switch Rows 1 & 3**
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 3 & -1 & -2 &  4 \\ 
 1 & -1 &  4 & -4 \\ 
 2 &  1 &  0 &  3
\end{array}\right]$$
Next step is $E_2 - E_1/3 = E_2$.

---

So I get
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 3 & -1 & -2 & 4 \\ 
 0 & -1/3 & 16/3 & -2/3 \\ 
 2 & 1 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right]$$

But the notes from my professor for the second step
are
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 3 & -1 & -2 & 4 \\ 
 0 & -2/3 & 14/3 & -16/3 \\ 
 2 & 1 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right]$$

**What am I doing wrong? I can’t find my arithmetic mistake…**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line becomes 
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1-1 & -1 - (-1/3) & 4 - (-2/3) & -4 -4/3
\end{array}\right]$.

We have $1-1=0,\, -1 - (-1/3) = -1 +1/3 = -2/3,\, 4-(-2/3)=4+2/3=12/3+2/3=14/3,\,-4-4/3=-12/3-4/3=-16/3$.

Thus, your professor was correct for all of them.

Comment: I see my mistakes now, god bless

Answer (score 1):

You want to add $-1/3$ times the first row to the second. Looking at the second entry there you have $\frac{-1}{3} (-1)$ and you want to add that to the entry right below the $-1$, which is in position $(1,2)$, i.e., $-1$ in position $(2,2)$.

I.e., the entry in the $(2,2)$ position becomes $-1+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{-2}{3}$, and not $\frac{-1}{3}$ as you claimed.

Similarly for all other entries.